# Message Length Encryption Failure using Perl Crypt::PK::DH

Tags: perl, public-key-encryption

Why does a change in Message Length Cause the decryption to fail in the Below Snippet?

I Receive the following Error "FATAL: dh_encrypt_key failed: Invalid hash specified. at C:/Perl/perl/site/lib/Crypt/PK/DH.pm line 225."

Occurs on Perl (v5.14.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread,  Win10

```
use Crypt::PK::DH;

my $pub = Crypt::PK::DH->new('bob_pub_key.gpg');

print "encrypting secret message... \n";

my $ct = $pub->encrypt("1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10");  # This Works

# my $ct = $pub->encrypt("1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-"); # Why Does This Not Work???

my $priv = Crypt::PK::DH->new('bob_priv_key.gpg');

print "decrypting secret message \n";

my $pt = $priv->decrypt($ct);

print "$pt\n";
```

Comment: Looking at the source, the digest algorithm used must produce a digest that's at least the size of the plaintext. The default algorithm is SHA1, which produces 20-byte digests.

Comment: Looks like DH is meant to be used to exchange a key to be used for (more efficient) symetric encryption. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange).

Comment: Roger, that makes sense - appreciate the feedback! Thank you